# Kusto table creation where column name from file or list

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I want to create a kusto table where columns are result of some function or from a file.

I have a file which contains column name and datatype as key value pair.
Query should take column name and datatype from file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just script it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/#client-libraries

Answer (score 0):

you can use any such language like java script or C# to do so, but again you have need to define the data type along with column name, so if you have proper data type defined along with column in list/file then you can read the file and create table on the fly.